# Laravel Vuejs form builder

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In my project i have some events, each with a number of tags.
These tags are defined by the administrator user.
Some of these tags may have parameters.
For example, an email tag has two "Sender" and "Receiver" parameters.
Or the transfer tag has 2 parameters "From" and "To". and etc.
Do I have to use the form builder?
How do I implement this using Laravel and Vuejs?

Answer (score 0):

Use Vue JS Component in Laravel like this.

Create Contact.vue component inside resources\assets\js\components then place your Vuejs there.

```
<template>
      <div>
        <h1>Contacts</h1>
        <form action="#" @submit.prevent="createContact()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input v-model="contact.name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input v-model="contact.email" type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New Contact</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      export default {
        data: function(){
          return {
            contact:{
              name:'',
              email:'',
            }
          }
        },
        methods: {
          createContact: function(){
          //call axios to submit the form values in your Laravel controller method
          let self = this
           axios.post('/contact/store', params)
              .then(function(){
                self.contact.name = '';
                self.contact.email = '';
              })
              .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
              });
            console.log(this.contact);
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

In app.js file inside \resources\assets\js add the component

```
Vue.component('contacts', require('./components/Contacts.vue'));
```

Finally, call the contacts component inside your blade file.

```
   <div class="container">
      <div id="app">
        <contacts></contacts>
      </div>
    </div>
```